# @NonNull and @Nullable annotations - Does it effect the performance in Android?

Tags: android, annotations

Do **@NonNull** and **@Nullable** annotations effect the performance in Android during runtime? I mean they only have the purpose to support LINT and other tools to detect possible bugs, so they probably/hopefully will be ignored during compiling. Do you have any sources for me proving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a little experiment I created the following method in an Android app:

```
private void test(@NonNull Object o) {
    o.toString();
}
```

Compiled the project, 'un-compiled' it with [ApkTool](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) and took a look at the [smali](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali) file:

```
.method private test(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    .locals 0
    .param p1, "o"    # Ljava/lang/Object;
        .annotation build Landroid/support/annotation/NonNull;
        .end annotation
    .end param

    .prologue
    .line 22
    invoke-virtual {p1}, Ljava/lang/Object;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

    .line 23
    return-void
.end method
```

So the `Nonnull` annotation is not actually removed from the code at compile time.

I could though turn off the checks in Android studio, call the test-method with `null` as an argument and compile the app. It then crashes with a `NullPointerExeption` at `o.toString()` of course, but there is no hint of the VM actually using the annotation to check the parameter at runtime. Exactly what laalto said in his answer.

I do wonder though if the VM would be capable of doing so and throwing an exception when the method is called with the `null` argument.

Answer (score 4):

The `@NonNull` and `Nullable` annotations are declared with `CLASS` [retention policy](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html). They are seen in the compiled bytecode but can be ignored by the VM at runtime.

If you're concerned about performance, run an experiment to see if it is an issue for you. I would hypothesize that class-retention annotations don't add any significant overhead.

(If the retention policy was runtime *and* the annotations were queried via reflection at runtime, *then* there would be performance issues especially in the [past](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7811).)

Comment: Do you know if the VM had the means to enforce the annotation at runtime (if it 'wanted' to)?

Comment: @Ascorbin These annotations are meant for compile-time static analyzers and not for runtime VM. At runtime you get `NullPointerException` when a nullability contract was violated by the programmer and nothing special is needed for that.